# Seperating the information from output in my scraping code (beautifulsoup + python)

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

The profile I am scraping is https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/robin-d-gross-39828 . I am getting both Education and Professional Associations printing out together, how can I separate these two?

```
for item in soup.find_all("dl", {"class": "description-list list-with-badges"}):
    y = item.find_all("span",attrs={"itemprop":"name"})
    if y:
        print("Education:", item.get_text(strip=True, separator= '|').split('|'))
```

Output is:

```
Education: ['Santa Clara University School of Law', 'J.D. ', '  Law', '1998', 'Honors:', 'Awarded "Certificate in High Technology Law"', 'Activities:', 'Editor, Santa Clara Computer & High Technology Law Journal;  Editor-in-Chief, The Advocate, Santa Clara University Law School Newspaper.']
Education: ['Michigan State University, James Madison College', 'B.A. ', '  Political Philosophy', '1995', 'Honors:', 'Overseas Study Program in Caribbean and South America, Summer Semester 1994Vice-President, MSU Adventure Club']
Education: ['Michigan State University, James Madison College', 'B.A. ', '  International Relations', '1995']
Education: ['California State Bar', '# 200701', 'Member', 'Current']
Education: ['California Bar Association', 'Member', 'Current']
Education: ['San Francisco Bar Association', 'Member', 'Current']
Education: ['American Bar Association', 'Member', 'Current']
Education: ['Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) - Noncommercial Stakeholders Group', 'Executive Committee', '2010', '- Current']
Education: ['Executive Committee of FreeMuse', 'Member', '2009', '-', '2016']
Education: ['Public Interest Registry - Advisory Council', 'Member', '2012', '-', '2014']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `"class": "description-list list-with-badges"` to fetch your items. If you look at the code, you'll see that both items in `Education` and `Professional Associations` have these classes.

If you want to catch them separately, you could use the `itemtype` tag. `http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity` is the `Education` tag's value and `http://schema.org/Organization` for `Professional Associations`.

Comment: Awesome wasnt aware but ty.

Comment: I am using the same idea you presented to try to get the information on Awards, but it looks like there are no unique tags, like there was with Professional Associations and Education, do you know what I may do in such a case?

Comment: You could use a text based search first to find the `Awards` div, and then using `.parent` to get all the information of this `div`.

Comment: I tried this:   for item in soup.findAll("div",{"class":"heading-3 block-title iconed-heading font-w-bold"}):
 j=item.find_parent('div')
 print("AwardS:",item.get_text(strip=True, separator= '|').split('|'))